# Reducing a certain amount from everyone's data in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a MySQL database. I want to reduce certain data using Cronjob at certain times of the week.

(Table name: Accounts)

```
username | hunger | hp
         |        |
Dworczyk | 100    | 100
Mateusz  | 100    | 95
```

Let's say a random amount will be reduced from the hunger data of everyone in the table above. In other words, the hunger data of all the people above will be reduced.

```js
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const { con, pool } = require("./container/mysql.js")

let random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

let job = new CronJob('0 0 * * *', function() {
    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username = 'Dworczyk'`, async (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        pool.query(`UPDATE Accounts SET hunger = ${rows[0].hunger} - ${random_number}`);
    });
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');

job.start();
```

What I did above is simple subtraction from a single person. It shouldn't just be tied to "Dworczyk". How can I make transactions on everyone without using the `WHERE` key?

Comment: Should it be the same random number for every user or a random number for each user individually? It also wouldn't harm, if you tagged your host language. That doesn't look like MySQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract from the column itself rather than a variable.

Also, use parametrized queries rather than substituting variables into the SQL.

```
pool.query('UPDATE Accounts SET hunger = hunger - ?', [random_number], function(err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the question mark used for? Does it represent the [random_number]?

Comment: It's the placeholder that gets filled in by the `random_number` parameter.

Comment: If we increase the parameters at the end, how should we change the question marks? is it like ?[0] etc.

Comment: Each `?` is replaced by the corresponding value in the array.

Comment: `[param1, param2, param3, ...]`. I suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: So a second used "?" equals the second parameter. Thank you, I didn't know that, I'm going to read it.